# How to call `one_hot` in `keras` in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras

I have below code in `python3`:

```
docs = ['Well done!',
        'Good work',
        'Great effort',
        'nice work',
        'Excellent!',
        'Weak',
        'Poor effort!',
        'not good',
        'poor work',
        'Could have done better.']
# define class labels
labels = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0])
from keras import backend as K


# integer encode the documents
vocab_size = 50
encoded_docs = [K.one_hot(d, vocab_size) for d in docs]
print(encoded_docs)
```

Basically I tries to encode each word from the list but I got this error:

`TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'indices' has DataType string not in list of allowed values: uint8, int32, int64`
.

What is wrong in my code? It seems like a type error but I don't understand why.

Comment: You could in some cases try [keras.preprocessing.text.one_hot](https://keras.io/preprocessing/text/#one_hot) instead of [keras.backend.one_hot](https://keras.io/backend/#one_hot), although since it uses hashing and does not guarantee uniqueness, the answer below may suit you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keras `one_hot` method expects the first argument to be integer type(in your case index of the words). So you need first to map each word to unique integer before using `one_hot` method.

```py
docs = ['Well done!',
        'Good work',
        'Great effort',
        'nice work',
        'Excellent!',
        'Weak',
        'Poor effort!',
        'not good',
        'poor work',
        'Could have done better.']
all_words = set()
for s in docs:
    for word in s.split():
        all_words.add(word)
all_words = list(all_words)
# define class labels
labels = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0])
from keras import backend as K


# integer encode the documents
vocab_size = len(all_words)
encoded_docs = [[K.one_hot(all_words.index(word), vocab_size) for word in d.split()] for d in docs]
print(encoded_docs)
```

If  you want to encode punctuation as separate words, then you can use `re` module to split words.

```py
import re
import string

encoded_docs = [[K.one_hot(all_words.index(word), vocab_size) for word in re.findall("[\w]+|["+string.punctuation+"]", d) for d in docs]
```

Answer (score 0):

without any conversion to integer, I used :

```
encoded_docs = [keras.preprocessing.text.one_hot(d,vocab_size)for d in docs]
```

It works !